# Is it Proper a way to select count(*) from two different tables

Tags: mysql

i want `count(*)` from two different tables and a value from third table

like this:

table A: `select count(*) from TABLE_A where grp_id = 1`

table B: `select count(*) from TABLE_B where grp_id = 1`

table C: `select totalcount from TABLE_C where grp_id = 1 and AND UserID = 1`

so , i framed this query:

```
select ifnull((select count(*) from TABLE_A where grp_id = 1),0) + ifnull((select count(*) from TABLE_B where grp_id = 1),0)
```

will it be efficient way to do?

Comment: no need for ifnull, count always return >= 0

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, that's totally fine.

The subqueries won't add any appreciable overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Ramesh,

I think that would be efficient but why don't you do that on server side ? I think it would be more flexible then writing this SQL query.

Comment: @Michael: I mean in C#,PHP,Java whatever he is using for making webpage, if there is any involved.

Comment: hmm.. ok. "...but why don't you do that on server side?" purported he is doing it on client-side(c#,php,java,etc).  i see his last query, it is server-side as it gets.